# Add all prime numbers in a range to an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop

General Question: what would I put where the comments are in my for loop?

In depth Question: In a program on Android Dev Studio, I have the basic "Hello World" program set up (type a message into a text box, click the "send" button, the message appears on the next activity).

However, I want to adapt that program into one where a person would type a number into the text box, and the program will find all the prime numbers between 1 and the number inputted.

The following is my code so far, with comments on the section with syntax I don't know how to format.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    int limit = Integer.parseInt(message);
    int a[limit];
    for(int i = 1; i <= limit; i++)
    {
        if(i%2 = 0 || i%3 = 0 || i%5 = 0 || i%7 = 0)
        { 
            //I want the program to move on to the next number
        }
        else
        {
            //I want this number to be added into the array
        }
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(a);
    //a being the name of the array created
```

The other issue I have would be that **the program would not recognize 1, 2, 3, 5, and 7 as prime numbers, due to them being divided by themselves**, and therefore having the remainder be 0.

Is there a way to **set up part of the array before inputting the rest of the terms?** If not, **is there a way I could edit the program so that those numbers would appear as prime?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should help you:

```
    String primeNumbers = "";
    for (int i = 1, num = 0; i <= limit; i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (num = i; num >= 1; num--) {
            if (i % num == 0) {
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }
        if (counter == 2) {

            primeNumbers += i + " ";
        }
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(primeNumbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using a well established API to find your primes, like [`org.apache.commons.math3.primes.Primes`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/math3/primes/Primes.html). It provides you a method `nextPrime(int n)` that you could use like this in your example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(limit);

for(int i = 1; i <= limit; i = Primes.nextPrime(i))
{
    a.add(i++);  
}
```